# Binding rectangles with checkbox

Tags: javafx

A treeview in which user can add as many root and coordinates as he want. Coordinates generate 
rectangles, which are shown horizontally on root node, here is code

```
import javafx.scene.Node;

abstract class MyNode {
    private final String label;
    private Node rectangle;

    MyNode(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    Node getRectangle() {
        return rectangle;
    }

    void setRectangle(Node rectangle) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
}

class MyRootNode extends MyNode {
    MyRootNode(String label) {
        super(label);
    }
}
class MyCoordinateNode extends MyNode {
    MyCoordinateNode(String label) {
        super(label);
    }
}
```

and the Main class is

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private static int rootNr = 0;
    private static int coordinateNr = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final Map<TreeItem<MyNode>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        TreeItem<MyNode> mainTree = new TreeItem<>(new MyRootNode("Main System"));
        mainTree.setExpanded(true);

        TreeView<MyNode> treeView = new TreeView<>(mainTree);
        treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new AddMenuTreeCell());
        treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            final TreeItem<MyNode> treeItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (treeItem.getValue() instanceof MyRootNode) {
                root.setCenter(getRootsPanel(treeItem));
            } else {
                root.setCenter(map.get(treeItem));
            }
        });

        root.setLeft(treeView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<MyNode> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

        AddMenuTreeCell() {
            MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Root");
            MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Coordinates");
            menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1, newitem2);
            newitem1.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<MyNode> item = new TreeItem<>(new MyRootNode("Root" + rootNr++));
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item);
            });
            newitem2.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<MyNode> uxItem1 = new TreeItem<>(new MyCoordinateNode("X"));
                map.put(uxItem1, getRightPane(uxItem1));

                TreeItem<MyNode> uyItem1 = new TreeItem<>(new MyCoordinateNode("Y"));
                map.put(uyItem1, getRightPane(uyItem1));

                TreeItem<MyNode> newLeaf = new TreeItem<>(new MyRootNode("Coordinates" + coordinateNr++));
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uxItem1);
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uyItem1);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(MyNode item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (!isEditing()) {
                    setText(item.getLabel());
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (item instanceof MyRootNode) {
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static BorderPane getRightPane(final TreeItem<MyNode> curTreeItem) {
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect = getRectangle(textf1, textf2, Color.BLUE);
                root1.setCenter(rect);
                curTreeItem.getValue().setRectangle(rect);
            }
        });
        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect = getRectangle(textf1, textf2, Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect);
                curTreeItem.getValue().setRectangle(rect);
            }
        });

        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root1.setLeft(vbox);
        return root1;
    }

    private static Rectangle getRectangle(TextField textf1, TextField textf2, final Color blue) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
        rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
        rect.setFill(null);
        rect.setStroke(blue);

        return rect;
    }

    private static BorderPane getRootsPanel(final TreeItem<MyNode> treeItem) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();


        CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("Change order");
        CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Change View");
        VBox vbox = new VBox(30, box1,box2);



        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        final List<MyNode> coordinateNodes = getCoordinateNodes(treeItem);
        for (final MyNode coordinateNode : coordinateNodes) {
            if (coordinateNode.getRectangle() != null) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> hbox.getChildren().addAll(coordinateNode.getRectangle()));
            }
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> root.setLeft(hbox));

        return root;
    }

    private static List<MyNode> getCoordinateNodes(final TreeItem<MyNode> treeItem) {
        final List<MyNode> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (treeItem.getValue() instanceof MyRootNode) {
            for (final TreeItem<MyNode> child : treeItem.getChildren()) {
                result.addAll(getCoordinateNodes(child));
            }
        } else {
            result.add(treeItem.getValue());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My Question is, How to bind all newly generated rectangles which are shown in root with these two check-boxes that if first checkbox is selected then order of rectangle should be changed like(1,2,3 to 3,2,1), with second checkbox rectangles are moved from horizontal to vertical view and if both checked then both features are applied.

due to the fact that user can add rectangle as many as he want, it is difficult for me to bind all of them.

i tried by putting bounty on the question but still didn't get any response. Please i am desperately searching help on this problem . Please

i will be very Thankfull.